# Braintree Credit/debit integration not working

Tags: android, paypal, braintree, braintree-sandbox

I'm using Braintree SDK for PayPal integration in my native android app. I'm using my Custom UI for entering the Card Details. Once the card Details are entered. SDK call for `card.tokenize` is called.

```
BraintreeFragment mBraintreeFragment;

    try {
        mBraintreeFragment = BraintreeFragment.newInstance( MainActivity.this, btToken);
        Card.tokenize(mBraintreeFragment, cardBuilder);
        Log.i("TAG", "getTokenized Card TRY::");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.i("TAG", "exception Card");
        Log.i("TAG", "Exception" + e);
    }
```

`mBraintreeFragment = BraintreeFragment.newInstance( MainActivity.this, btToken);` is throwing error on trying to tokenie.
error thrown is :::  `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method newInstance(Landroidx/appcompat/app/AppCompatActivity;Ljava/lang/String;)Lcom/braintreepayments/api/BraintreeFragment; in class Lcom/braintreepayments/api/BraintreeFragment; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.braintreepayments.api.BraintreeFragment' appears in /data/app/com.ust.fcs.wiwo-Eg4iuAwmHl6_q2RzdgkwGA==/base.apk) at com.ust.fcs.braintreesdklib.activities.MainActivity.getBraintreeDeviceData(MainActivity.java:549)`.  please suggest me a work around for it.

Answer (score 0):

MainActivity should extends AppCompatActivity starting from Braintree SDK v3 ("v2" is deprecated now).

Reference: https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/client-sdk/migration/android/v2

Answer (score 0):

This was due to the implementation of  Baintree dependencies, I have updated to :
 `implementation 'com.braintreepayments.api:braintree:3.14.0' implementation 'com.braintreepayments.api:drop-in:4.6.0'`, which solves
the above issue.